# How to create 64 bit teamspeak 3 plugin?

Tags: visual-c++, plugins, teamspeak

i've just started a story with creating plugins but i have a problem with example plugin that i've downloaded from here [TeamSpeak3 plugin sdk](http://dl.4players.de/ts/client/pluginsdk/)

It doesn't work on 64bit version of teamspeak 3.
How can i make it works?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work? Are there any error messages?

Comment: It doesn't load to teamspeak 3. There is an error "can't load plugin".

Comment: I was looking for solution i i found that it is beacause i use 64bit version of teamspeak 3.

Comment: Ohhh, now its working. :)